# Setting consistency level for Read operation in Azure CosmosDB Cassandra API

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I am writing a Java application that connects to a Cassandra database within Microsoft Azure CosmosDB. As per the documentation page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-consistency, cosmosdb has an option to set the consistency level for a read operation. I am, however, unable to find examples of how to do this while using the SQL API for cassandra. 
I am extending the example provided by Microsoft at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-cassandra-java-getting-started. The example uses the datastax driver cassandra.

Is it possible to set the consistency level using this driver?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?If so ,you could mark it for others' references.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't find anything about consistency settings in the [source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-cassandra-java-getting-started) you provided.Actually, the mechanism of Azure Cosmos DB’s Cassandra API consistency level is different from other cosmos db api(such as SQL api,Gremlin api etc.)

Please read the statements in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels-across-apis#cassandra-mapping).

When using Azure Cosmos DB’s Cassandra API:

- The write consistency level of Apache Cassandra is mapped to the
  default consistency level configured on your Azure Cosmos account.
- Azure Cosmos DB will dynamically map the read consistency level
  specified by the Cassandra client driver to one of the Azure Cosmos
  DB consistency levels configured dynamically on a read request.

So, based on my understanding,the consistency of cosmos db doesn't interfere with your driver's original consistency settings, but maps them according to the following table：

[image]

You could set the consistency with DataStax driver,referring to this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html).